# x11vnc crashes on signal 11 (segmentation fault) shortly after a client connects

Tags: debian, x11, x11vnc

#### background

Debian testing, kernel 5.9.0

#### symptoms

`x11vnc` server accepts my remote connection. Then, after about 20 seconds, the server crashes.
Log shows that as soon as the server initializes `xfixes`, it receives signal 11 (segmentation fault).
I'd link the issue to a system update, because it all used to run well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-noxfixes` to `x11vnc` server command line resolves the issue.